# How do you profile an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

What I would like to do is capture all the selects executing against a production Oracle database with all the parameters used for a period of time.
I would then rerun all the captured statements against a test system to verify changes made there will improve performance.

1. Capture SQL executing in production,
   primarily interested in selects
   rather then inserts and updates.
2. Restore a copy of production to a
   test server
3. Run the captured SQL recording
   the time taken.
4. Do performance tuning, indexes
   partitioning of tables etc.
5. Run the captured SQL to verify
   that the performance tuning was
   successful.

Is step 1 possible with Oracle and if so how is it done?  The capture needs to be done against all sessions and needs to capture the parameters used in the queries i.e. for the query select myfield from mytable where someotherfield = :value I need to replay with the actual value used for :value each time the select is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into "Real Application Testing"
It's an extra cost option for Oracle, but basically does exactly as you've described

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/08-jan/o18dbasereplay.html is a good resource too.

Comment: This is an 11g only feature.  I am looking for something that works with 10g.

Comment: It only does the playback in 11G.  But you can capture a 10G workload.